# Microsoft 2010 Information Worker Demonstration Virtual Machine on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, ubuntu-10.10, vhd, sharepoint-2010

Since I'm looking to improve my Sharepoint knowledge, I downloaded the 2010 Information Worker Demonstration and Evaluation Virtual Machine (SP1) from Microsoft

https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417

Now I understand that VirtualBox (4.1.4) supports the .vhd format, so I created a new virtual machine with the .vhd as the hard disk. However now it doesn't boot. Does anyone have any ideas?

Alternatively are there any other virtualization solutions, so I can get this virtual machine running with an Ubuntu (10.10) host?

Comment: You can try using the commandline tools `vboxmanage clonehd` or `vboxmanage convertfromraw` to clone / convert the vhd to a vdi image and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion, but I found the solution in this blog post

http://ollysense.blogspot.com/2010/05/virtualbox-using-hyper-v-vhd-image.html

It turns out you can get the vhd image to work under virtualbox by mounting it under an ide controller rather than a sata.

It seems to be working fine, but I'm still experimenting so there may be other compatibility issues.

Incidentally this image needs a huge amount of RAM. So you should be running 64bit linux or the 32 bit with pae enabled.